# jquery click function sends to refering page not the url'd page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a jquery ajax click function for a form, when it sends without any inputs it sends to the correct php page, but when user inputs have been filled in it sends to the same page it sends from, also it is sent as post and gets changed to get

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#videoToUpload").click(function() {

var vidName = $("#vidName").val();
var videoDescription = $("#videoDescription").val();
var albumName1 = $("#choosevidCat").val();
var vidFile =$("#video").val();

  // Put an animated GIF image insight of content
  $("#loader").empty().html('<img src="/images/loader.gif" class="vidloader1"/>');

        $.post("includes/vid_upload.inc.php",{vidName: vidName, videoDescription: videoDescription, albumName1: albumName1,  vidFile: vidFile}, function(json)
         {

            if(json.result === "success") {

        $("#viduploadResult").html( "The Video "+vidName+" has been Uploaded!");


//        // First remove all the existing options
//       $('#choosevidCat').empty();
//
//        // Load the content:
//        $('#choosevidCat').load(location.href + "#choosevidCat > *");

    }else{
        $("#viduploadResult").html(json.message);
    }   

         });
    });
})
</script>
```

html (with some embedded php):

```
 <div id="title">Upload Videos</div>
  <div class="vidUpload">
    <form id="vidUpload">
<input name="vidName" type="text" required="required" id="vidName" placeholder="Enter Video Name Here" title="Video Name">
<br>
<textarea name="videoDescription" id="videoDescription" required class="videoDescription" placeholder="Enter Video Description Here" title="Enter Video Description Here"></textarea>

<select name="select" required class="choosevidCat" id="choosevidCat">
<option value="">Choose the Catagory for your Video Here</option>
            <?php 
    $sql = ("SELECT albumId, albumName, albumSelect FROM albums");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$albumid = ($row['albumId']);
$album_name = ($row['albumName']);
$album_name1 = ($row['albumSelect']);
echo "<option value=".$album_name1. ">$album_name</option>";
}

?>


<option id="createCat" value="createCatagory">Create New Catagory Here</option>
</select>

<input type="file" name="video" id="video">
<input type="submit" name="videoToUpload" id="videoToUpload" value="Upload">

</form>
<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="viduploadResult"></div>
```

can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please, I'm at a loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the `<form>` tags, and change the `<input type="submit">` to `<input type="button">` which will stop the HTML form trying to handle the post. The reason it is sending as GET is because it is the default `method` for forms (And you havn't specified a method).

Your jQuery takes care of handling the input fields, and posting the data, so you don't need the form as such.

Comment: Only if you don't care about standards...the HTML standard requires input elements be inside a form element

Answer (score 2):

Change the button to input type="button" to prevent automatic form submission

Comment: @user3370876 Thankyou very much, that did briefly go through my mind but I didnt think it relevent, shows you should trust your instinct at times, lol